# jQuery sending undefined "_" parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to write a script that gets COVID-19 numbers from the Ontario Database, but I keep getting the following error:

> "invalid value \"_\""

Upon further investigation, the URL that is trying to be accessed contains the following parameter:

```
&_=1610496351832
```

As you can see in my code below, I never define such a variable:

```
    var data = {
      resource_id: '8a89caa9-511c-4568-af89-7f2174b4378c' // the resource id
    };
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: data,
        url: 'https://data.ontario.ca/api/3/action/datastore_search'
    });
```

Is there any way I can remove the `_` object from the request?

The file I am trying to access is located at the following URL, where data is the `resource_id`.

```
https://data.ontario.ca/api/3/action/datastore_search?resource_id=8a89caa9-511c-4568-af89-7f2174b4378c
```

Comment: What is `data`? What produces the error? What appends the `_` parameter?

Comment: It's the page where the data is located. I'll update the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an automatic value generated by JQuery to avoid the cache.

Add the following to your script if you want to get rid of the underscore param:

```
    var data = {
      resource_id: '8a89caa9-511c-4568-af89-7f2174b4378c' // the resource id
    };
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: data,
        type:'GET',
        cache: true,
        url: 'https://data.ontario.ca/api/3/action/datastore_search'
    });
```

It only occurs in GET requests, you can play around with this setting. But remember, the automatic underscore param is included intentionally to avoid the request cashing.